# TextX state machine model not getting parsed properly

Tags: python, syntax-error, dsl, state-machine, textx

I am trying to build a state machine for microwave oven. I am designing it such that it has only two functionalities as of now : bake and clean. It will have 3 states: idle, baking and cleaning. While transitioning into a state, the state machine will perform actions. The actions are commands like run the timer, lock the door, turn on light inside, etc. I am trying to group many of such commands into a command group and pass that command group to the actions. Events are user performed events events like start baking, start cleaning, etc.

My command grouping logic is returning syntax errors. I am stuck on how to make sense out of the error and how to fix the issue.

PFB my meta model and oven model.

Meta-model:

```
StateMachine:
    'events'
        events+=Event
    'end'

    'commands'
        commands+=Command
    'end'

    ('commandgroups'
        commandGroupBlocks+=CommandGroupBlock        
    'end')? 

    states+=State
;

Keyword:
    'end' | 'events' | 'state' | 'actions' | 'commandgroups' | 'group' | 'groupend'
;

Event:
    name=SMID code=ID
;

Command:
    name=SMID code=ID
;

CommandGroupBlock:
    'group' name=SMID
        groupCommands+=[Command|SMID]       
    'groupend'
;

State:
    'state' name=ID
        ('actions' '{' actions+=[CommandGroupBlock|Command] '}')?
        (transitions+=Transition)?
    'end'
;

Transition:
    event=[Event|SMID] '=>' to_state=[State]
;

SMID:
    !Keyword ID
;

Comment:
    /\/\*(.|\n)*?\*\//
;
```

Oven model:

```
events
  bakeOn            E_BKON
  cleanOn           E_CLON
  cleanOff          E_CLOF
end

commands
  timerInitial      C_TMIN  
  timerRunning      C_TMRN
  lockDoor          C_D1LK
  unlockDoor        C_D1UL
  magnetronOn       C_MGON
  magnetronOff      C_MGOF
  internalLightOn   C_ILON
  internalLightOff  C_ILOF
  turnTableOn       C_TTON
  turnTableOff      C_TTOF
  cleanerOn         C_CLON    
  cleanerOff        C_CLOF
end

commandgroups
  group resetCommands
    unlockDoor
    timerInitial
    magnetronOff
    internalLightOff
    turnTableOff
    cleanerOff
  groupend
  group commonActiveCommands
    lockDoor  
    internalLightOn
    timerRunning  
  groupend
end

state idle
  actions {resetCommands}
  bakeOn => baking
  cleanOn => cleaning
end

state baking
  actions {commonActiveCommand magnetronOn turnTableOn}
end

state cleaning
  actions {commonActiveCommand cleanerOn turnTableOff}
  cleanOff => idle
end
```

The error i am getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "state_machine.py", line 70, in <module>
    model = meta_model.model_from_file(sys.argv[1])
  File "/workspace/dsl-state-machine-oven/demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textx/metamodel.py", line 661, in model_from_file
    return self.internal_model_from_file(
  File "/workspace/dsl-state-machine-oven/demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textx/metamodel.py", line 709, in internal_model_from_file
    model = self._parser_blueprint.clone().get_model_from_str(
  File "/workspace/dsl-state-machine-oven/demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textx/model.py", line 372, in get_model_from_str
    self.parse(model_str, file_name=file_name)
  File "/workspace/dsl-state-machine-oven/demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arpeggio/__init__.py", line 1525, in parse
    self.parse_tree = self._parse()
  File "/workspace/dsl-state-machine-oven/demo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/textx/model.py", line 332, in _parse
    raise TextXSyntaxError(message=e.message,
textx.exceptions.TextXSyntaxError: /workspace/dsl-state-machine-oven/oven.sm:39:25: Expected ID => 'etCommands*}   bakeOn'
```

Please help me out with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The problem is that you are trying to reference either a command or command group from the state actions. But the syntax is not correct.

```
State:
    'state' name=ID
        ('actions' '{' actions+=[CommandGroupBlock|Command] '}')?
        (transitions+=Transition)?
    'end'
;
```

Part `actions+=[CommandGroupBlock|Command]` would mean `match one or more CommandGroupBlock using Command to match the name`.

What you actually wanted is:

```
GroupOrCommand: Command | CommandGroupBlock;

State:
    'state' name=ID
        ('actions' '{' actions+=[GroupOrCommand|SMID] '}')?
        (transitions+=Transition)?
    'end'
;
```

Here we introduced a new abstract rule `CommandOrGroup` and then we are linking to this rule using `SMID` to parse names.

BTW, there is also a typo in the model: `commonActiveCommand` -> `commonActiveCommands`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That instantly fixed it. I have better understanding of textX grammar as well. My experiment was inspired from your example on textX.

Comment: You have stumbled upon a common problem. It is unfortunate that `|` is chosen to separate rule to link to from the rule used for parsing in link rule reference, as it is often confused with ordered choice. We'll probably change this separator in the future.

Comment: Thank you.. The documentation also took me to ordered choice only